# reinterpret_cast does not have defined behavior

Tags: c++

SO i have two classes `Tuna` and `Carp` which have the member methods `becomeDinner` and `Talk` respectively:
Now I have this code:

```cpp
Tuna* myDum = new Tuna();
auto myCastedDum = reinterpret_cast<Carp*>(myDummy);
myCastedDum->Talk();
```

In my book it says:

> Again, definitely not. `reinterpret_cast` changed only the interpretation of the pointer, and did not change the object being pointed to (that is still a `Tuna`). Calling a `Talk()` function on a `Tuna` object will not give the results you are looking for,  and could possibly cause an application error.

Now this seams to not be the case, when I try to call the `talk` method on `myCastedDum` it works as if it was a `Carp` object and when I try to call `becomeDinner()` it tells me that it isn't a member, I don't understand, we cast it to Carp explicitely with `reinterpret_cast` so why would that be unexpected if we explicitely tell the compiler to do it?

What does changing the interpretation of the pointer mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling a method of one object when it's really a different object is undefined behaviour. What's not to understand?

Comment: The book forgot to mention that a very common symptom of triggering undefined behaviour is that the code accidentally does what you expect.

Comment: The thing about C++ is that, at least by default, it doesn't give you pretty errors if you break the rules. Your code causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which can have any effect: it can "work", it can glitch randomly, or anything.

Comment: see the updated post

Comment: @Quentin The book seems to be saying that it `will not give the results you are looking for` which is incorrect.

Comment: @john that is my point, yes.

Comment: @Alex If you call a method of one type using an pointer to an unrelated type it is undefined behaviour. It doesn't matter how you got there, whether you used reinterpret_cast or anything else, it's **always** undefined behaviour. You can't pretend that an object is a different type to what it really is.

Comment: This actually seems exactly like how Undefined Behavior seems to go most of the time. It works fine while you're testing it, then breaks on you at an inconvenient time when you're not thinking about it anymore. (The asker just hasn't got to the second phase yet.)

Comment: the last statement  is strange though, I don't know any compiler which acts like that, unless `Carp` was incomplete type

Comment: @john Thank you guys for all your answers from what you are saying I understand that is undefined behavior, however if I explicitly tell the compiler -> transform me this object into another object and it works ,why is that undefined? Also would it be possible for you guys to rephrase the book's statement in an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"if I explicitly tell the compiler -> transform me this object into another object and it works"* Look up "strict aliasing". What your code does is called a *strict aliasing violation*.

Comment: you're transforming poiter. Object is same, but because its not a virtual method, it would call a method of class you transformed to. There will be no internalization\conversion, of memory, the pointed object didn't change.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` does **not** transform one arbitrary object into another object. How would that even be possible? All you are changing in the type of the pointer, the object is still the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the answers, but there is too much informations to process, would it possible to formulate an answer if possible.

Comment: It is undefined behavior because in C++ you cannot transform one object into another object, with a waive of a hand like that. C++ does not work this way, and the only answer that anyone can give you is that [demons that fly of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) may or may not cause actual harm.

Comment: See updated post, would it be possible for an answer, i'll upvote :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your misunderstanding seems to be that in this code

```
Tuna* myDummy = new Tuna();
auto myCastedDum = reinterpret_cast<Carp*>(myDummy);
myCastedDum->Talk();
```

you think that `reinterpret_cast` is changing your `Tuna` object into a `Carp` object. That's not true. All it is doing is converting a Tuna pointer into a Carp pointer. But that Carp pointer is still pointing at a Tuna object, in other words the underlying object has not changed.

So when you use the Carp pointer to call a Carp method you get undefined behaviour, because there is no Carp object for the Carp method to work on.

The reason you are able to call `Carp::Talk()` is that all the compiler is checking is the type of the pointer. You do have a Carp pointer, even if it not pointing at a Carp object, so the compiler will let you call Carp::Talk. Using `reinterpret_cast` is a way of overriding the normal safety checks that the language has. That's why it should be used with care.

Comment: Thank you,  but then why can  I call `Carp::Talk()` if i'm not poiting to a `Carp` object, is this some sort of compiler prediction?

Comment: All the compiler is checking is the type of the pointer. You do have a Carp pointer, even if it not pointing at a Carp object, so the compiler will let you call a `Carp::Talk`. `reinterpret_cast` is a way of overriding the normal safety checks that the language has. That's why it should be used with care.

Comment: Thank you very much, would it be possible for you to include your answer to my comment in your answer? kind regards.